# Fatal Python error when trying to read the man pages

Tags: 16.04, python, manpage

Every time I try and run `man`, I get a Fatal Python error. For example: `man grep` .I've tried `man --help`, `man --version`, `man -[h|v]` etc.

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This didn't use to be the case (i.e. I used to be able to view the man pages), but I have no idea what I did that might have caused this. I even tried to reinstall `man-db`, to no avail.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: output of `echo $PATH`:

`/home/leslie/bin:/home/leslie/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

output of `python --version`:

`Python 2.7.12`

EDIT 2: `whereis man`:

`man: /usr/bin/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz`

`dpkg --verify man-db` gives no output

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $PATH` and `python --version`. [Edit] your question with it, please.

Comment: Does `man -P /usr/bin/less grep` work?

Comment: @steeldriver nope. Same error

Comment: Could you add the output of `whereis man` please? Also, `dpkg --verify man-db`. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the output of `PIPELINE_DEBUG=1 man grep`?  I suspect that one of the child processes that `man` runs (perhaps the pager) is the culprit, but that output should help narrow it down.